# How to accommodate two dependent fact tables in the same star schema?

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema

In a data warehouse how to store facts that are dependent on each other (one fact is a child of the other).?

Ex:

Transaction/Sale is a fact table in my warehouse.
But, I also have "comments/remarks" on each transaction/sale, which could be 0 - N  (usually N is never > 3 and 80% of the time 0)) per each sale/transaction.

Do I have to create a new fact for the "comments" table?

Answer (score 0):

If facts have the same grain then they can (but don't have to) be stored in the same fact table; if they have a different grain then they cannot be stored in the same fact table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would create a second fact table, sometimes called "factless fact table" or "bridge table". This is a many-to-many-relationship table connecting several dimension tables, but not containing any fact itself, only relationships.

Another typical example for this type of table in data warehouse literature is the case of a bank account having potentially more than one owner.

Comment: The two fact tables in the question are `1:N`, so an intermediate table implementing a `N:N` relationship is probably an overkill.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber If you only want to have fact and dimension tables, then you need that factless fact table as an intermediate fact table between the sales and the comment dimension. But you are right, if you are flexible with the type of tables you accept, then using a "many-to-one" relationship where actually a "one-to-many" one would suffice could be overhead. It just depends on the design rules - which might then depend on the framework you use. E. g. MS SSAS multidimensional cubes do not support one-to-many relationships, just many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach for the detail entity is to set up an **ordinary fact table**, with foreign key to all available dimensions (e.g. if the comments have their own posting dates) *plus* a foreign key towards the master fact table.

If the both fact tables are accessed often in common you will profit from an identical *partitioning schema*, e.g. range partitioning based on the sales day. This will help also to implement a unique rolling window concept for both fact tables.

In your example though you will possibly realize that a *free text comment* is not very valuable in dimensional modelling schema, so you may want to apply some sort of *feature selection* from the comments. If you manage to define a fixed number of such features, you may fall back to a one fact table schema simple adding those features as attributes.